# Implementation of jStepper

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I've spent the last couple of days trying to implement jStepper.js for an .ascx file.

- I've included jQuery.jstepper.js, jQuery.mousewheel.js, & jquery-1.10.2.js in the \jscript\ folder of my solution.
- Added the following lines in my .ascx file:

  ```
    <script src="/jscript/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/jscript/jquery.jstepper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ```
- Added the following lines within the  tags at the bottom of the .ascx file

  ```
    // Quantity
    var vField = $('#Quantity');
    vField.jStepper({
        minValue: 0, maxValue: 23, minLength: 1, maxLength: 3, normalStep:1, shiftStep: 5, ctrlStep: 10,
        onStep: function (objTextField, bDirection, bLimitReached) {
        $slider.slider("value", objTextField.val());
        updateAfterValuesChanged(); }
    });
  ```

When I put an alert() into jquery.jstepper.js, the alert shows, but jstepper is otherwise ignored. I'm sure that I'm missing something simple, but I just can't find it...

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that your element in the HTML has an id of "Quantity". Maybe it's all lower case ("quantity")?

Other things to note is that the call to bind jStepper has to occur after html is loaded in the browser.

Can we see the HTML you are trying to use?